# Installing Yacc or Bison for Mac

Tags: macos, installation, yacc, bison

I'm having trouble finding a Yacc or Bison that doesn't require using darwinports for Mac. If anyone has experience in this category any information will be great

Comment: I thought they came with the system, or with Xcode...

Comment: Yes, yacc/bison and flex should already be installed (at least if you have installed Xcode, and without Xcode you won't even have gcc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a working C compiler, it should be pretty trivial to build [byacc](http://invisible-island.net/byacc/byacc.html).

Comment: Although I do have a working C compiler, I'm taking a compiler construction class and the professor has specified that he wants us to use Yacc to parse our language with. Good point though.

Comment: @David: byacc is an implementation of yacc. I was suggesting that you download its source code and build it so you have a yacc you can use.

Comment: My mistake, I read your comment incorrectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone skipped the comments:

> yacc/bison and flex should already be installed (at least if you have installed Xcode, and without Xcode you won't even have gcc)

Thus, please check whether they exists before trying to install :)

Credits: @Chris Lutz and @Paul R